# Not able to access node server on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have a very basic node.js based http server that I want to use as a proxy. I setup the hostname and port in my system wide proxy settings for all http requests to make sure all the http requests go to this server.

The problem is - When I run the server locally, using `foreman start` and set localhost as hostname and 5000 as port, all my http requests are captured by this server. But when I deploy to Heroku, and using that host name and their port my page doesn't load.

Here is the code for the http server

```
var my_http = require("http");

var url = require('url');
var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 8080);

my_http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);

    response.writeHeader(200, {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain"
    });
    response.write(request.method + ": " + port + ': ' + url_parts.href);
    response.end();
}).listen(port);

console.log("Server Running on " + port);
```

**Note**
Foreman runs the application on port 5000 locally and runs on port 23536 on heroku.

**My understanding of the problem**
We have a website traffic filter in the company that doesn't allow us to access most of the websites, directly. You need to click on a link (saying continue) every time you access a them. My understanding is that since I am trying to access those blocked websites, they are getting blocked or something (Though the request is proxied)?

Comment: To check your blocking theory, did you try to access some non-blocked site through the proxy? Company firewalls usually can also do a deeper scan and check what you're really accessing.

Comment: Interesting, I am not able to access the sites that are actually allowed when I enable proxy.

Comment: So it is not a company firewall problem, except if heroku is protected on company firewall? If not, what does `heroku logs --tail` say when you try to use the app?

Comment: logs don't seem to have gotten my requests at all. (Sorry for the late response my system was not accessible to me over the weekend)

Comment: So it looks like your company firewall is taking those requests down before they even leave the company? Do you get the app working when accessing outside company?

Comment: No that doesn't work either. Its not the firewall. Im sure there is something wrong with Heroku setup. Could it be the port? The port which is determined by the env variable, might not actually be accessible publicly? Im just making wild guesses now :(

Comment: Did you try their support?

Comment: No, I am a free user. I don't think i have support feature.

Comment: Is there no other way to diagnose?

Comment: "Limited free technical support is available to all registered users of Heroku.". I don't know how to test it.
Are the ports open? Is the protocol configured correctly, can you telnet into the proper port instead of just getting the OS/browser do that?
Can you spin up a DigitalOcean droplet or some other server outside company, install node and try running the app there? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @Zlatko I will tryout your suggestions and get back to you on this. Thankyou so much!